# $k$-th derivative of a rational function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, polynomials, rational-functions

Let $f$ be the function given by
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{x+1}.
$$
As we easily check, the $k$-th derivative of $f$ is given by
$$
f^{(k)}(x) = (-1)^k \frac{k!}{(x+1)^{k+1}}.
$$
In particular $|f^{(k)}(x)| = \frac{k!}{(x+1)^{k+1}}$.

---

Suppose that $R_n$, $n \ge 1$ is a rational function such that

- $\displaystyle R_n(x) = \frac{P_n(x)}{Q_n(x)}$, where $P_n$ and $Q_n$ are polynomials,
- $R_n$ is proper, that is the degree of $Q_n$ is greater than the degree of $P_n$.
- all coefficients of $P_n$ and $Q_n$ are positive, (**EDIT:**) and $Q_n(0) \neq 0$,

and $R_n$ converges to $f$, in the sense that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} R_n(x) = f(x).
$$

> Does it follow that the $k$-th derivative of $R_n$ is uniformly (in $k$ and $x$) bounded on the positive axis by the $k$-th derivative of $f$? In other words, is it true that there exists $C > 0$ such that
> $$
> |R_n^{(k)}(x)| \le C \frac{k!}{(x+1)^{k+1}}, \qquad x > 0,\ k \ge 1?
> $$

Note that I would like to obtain the above estimate just for $x > 0$: in this interval $x \mapsto x + 1$ and $Q_n$ are positive (hence, nonzero).

Comment: No, for example $R_n(x) = \frac{1}{x+1} + \frac{1}{n x} \;\underset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow}\; f(x)$, but $R_n'(x) = -\frac{1}{(x+1)^2} - \frac{1}{n\,x^2}$ is unbounded near $0^+$.

Comment: @dxiv Nice. Does something change if we know that $0$ is not a root of $Q_n$? I've edited the question.

Comment: I wouldn't think it changes the answer, because pointwise convergence is a relatively weak requirement vs. uniform boundedness of derivatives. That said, the counterexample may be less obvious to find.

Comment: @dxiv That's what I thought, but I couldn't find a counterexample. I hoped that the rationality of the functions would make a difference.